# Should we merge these questions?

Tags: discussion

I think the following topics are quite the same, should we merge them? They are both quite long but still, the topic is about safety of boiled rotten meat.

[Can I eat rotten meat and carcass given enough cooking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/can-i-eat-rotten-meat-and-carcass-providing-enough-cooking)

[Can any waterborne pathogens survive boiling?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-any-waterborne-pathogens-survive-boiling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they should not be merged as they are two different questions. One is about meat and toxins (inorganic) and the other is about water and pathogens (organic).